# Python Pandas dataframe row entry is not comparable by condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, data-science

i read in a csv file with data. Everything works fine.
I can do a task like

```
df.loc[(df["BID"] == 7249)
```

But I would like to do the same with "Testschritt" like

```
df.loc[(df["Testschritt"] == "F1")
```

But all my entrys are *false*. But you can clearly see, that some entrys should be *true*.

I use the jupyter notebook.

Here the full code:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("<FILELOCATION>", ";")
df.loc[(df["Testschritt"] == "F1")
```

Output see in attached pictures[Output 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQAqe.png)
And here [Output 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDOGB.png)

Please give advise, Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems some sopaces before `F1` like `'  F1'`, you can remove them like:

```
df.loc[df["Testschritt"].str.strip() == "F1"]
```

Or ypu can assign output back:

```
df["Testschritt"] = df["Testschritt"].str.strip()
df.loc[df["Testschritt"] == "F1"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [str.contains()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) if you don't want exact match.

`df["Testschritt"].str.contains("F1")`

Answer (score 0):

you can do a simple thing like

`df[df['Testschritt']=='F1']`

to get the dataframe Testschritt column containing all the F1 values.
or to get the true False results

do like this

```
df['Testschritt'] == 'F1'
```